# R histogram to dynamic HTML / JS

Tags: javascript, html, r, histogram

After processin data in R, I need to build a standalone HTML to display histogram according to some parameters that user selects in a simple HTML/JS GUI.

I can not use Shinny / R Studio thing because users do not have R installed and I can not run any kind of a server for them to view this HTML. It should be possible for them copy a zip with HTML/JS to their machimes, unzip and just click on 'index.html' to view a histogram.

In R I have to process a table with the following fileds:

```
book, category, rating, cnt
```

This describes book ratings (from 1 to 5) which change during a year. Here 'cnt' is the number of times book had a particular rating. Using HTML GUI it should be possible to build histograms :

1) For a selected from an HTML combo-box 'book' - build distribution of this book ratings during the year

2) For an entered in HTML edit field - build 'rating' distribution of book counts with this rating

Any ideas how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: A Shiny app can be accessed by someone that does not have `R` installed.   There wouldn't even be a need to send a .zip file to their machines.

Comment: Ask them just to click run in `R-Fiddle`.

Comment: @Steven Can I run Shinny app without a server?

Comment: @zork, honestly, I'm not sure.  When I've deployed Shiny apps in the past, I've always written them in RStudio and deployed them to my account at shinyapps.io.  [This is a basic example](https://stevenranney.shinyapps.io/gradeInflation/), accessible by anyone with an internet connection, regardless of whether or not they're running R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several javascript libraries that can visaulize histograms. You can choose from them depending on your experience in javascript.

If it is just a simple interactive histogram chart, I recommend going with [c3.js](http://c3js.org/), because it does the job for the least effort. See an example of interactive histogram chart [here](http://c3js.org/samples/chart_bar.html).